# How to get the tag changeset after you clone or pull to a tag using mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, clone

As the definite guide [aptly points out](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html) (search for "Tags and cloning"):

> When you run `hg clone -r foo` to clone a repository as of tag `foo`, the new
>   clone will not contain any revision newer than the one the tag refers to,
>   including the revision where the tag was created. The result is that you'll
>   get exactly the right subset of the project's history in the new
>   repository, but **not the tag** you might have expected.

It means `hg tags` in your new clone does NOT show the `foo` tag. Same thing happens if you had cloned before `foo` tag was added, and you do `hg pull -r foo`.

(Digression: tag is about the only thing I don't quite get in hg. I understand there are advantages (e.g. merge) in putting it in a changeset, but it always feels weird to have meta data mixed with source code.)

It should be obvious that I'm asking for an automated way, instead of pulling the tag changeset as a separate manual step.

I know I could check for this scenario in an `incoming` hook (so it works for both clone and pull), or wrap `clone` and `pull`.

But is there a better/easier way?

---

UPDATE hg bug tracker already has [this issue](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094).

Comment: tags introducing changesets has got to be one of the few things I really dislike about Mercurial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done by post-clone/pull hooks, but there are a couple of crooks.

First, it only works for local repo, since you can't get the list of tags in a remote repo.

Second, dealing with clone/pull arguments and options is not trivial. (For clone I need to get the target repo, `-r`, `-u`, `-U`. For pull I need `-r` and `-u`.) I tried to use fancyopts, but it can't deal with global options, which are processed away in dispatch. I managed to hack dispatch to give me only the args and opts of a command, but it feels and looks ugly.

Using command wrapper would eliminate the second problem.

I hope one day hg will add an option to clone and pull to do it cleanly.

Comment: If you're using a hook can't you check the value of the `$HG_URL` variable.

Comment: I also need the pats and opts, but your mentioning of $HG_URL helped me find out from [man hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) that all pre/post hooks get $HG_PATS and $HG_OPTS.

Answer (score 3):

You want a giant hack with `bash` and an embedded Perl script? Well, here it is...

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "" || "$2" == "" || "$3" == "" ]]; then
  echo 'hgclonetag <src> <tgt> <tag>'
  exit 1;
fi

REV=`hg log -R $1 --rev $3: --limit=2 | perl -F: -lane 'if (/:([\dA-Fa-f]+)$/) {print $F[2] if defined($flag);$flag=1;}'`
hg clone --rev $REV $1 $2
```

This invokes the `hg log` command to extract the revision number *after* the first tag-related revision and then clones to this revision.

*Currently this does not work on remote repos: `-R` switch only works on local repos unfortunately.*

Comment: I surely would've accepted it had you not explicitly included git-tish words like "giant", "hack" (oops, did I just offend Lord Linus? *Remote thunder gathering...*), "bash", and "perl". I'm hoping for a small, elegant, hg-based, python solution :) +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Should be straightforward to Pythonize this using `os.system` and some regular expression matching. Nice comment: +1 yourself!

Comment: This wont work when you tag an old revision... if I do `hg tag -r 100 foo`, then I may be creating revision 1000. So fetching revision 101 wont bring in the tag.

Answer (score 3):

The more I think about it the more I'm convinced the *right* answer is to just clone everything and update to the tag, which can be done in a single step:

```
hg clone http://host/path#tagname
```

That gets you everything and then does `hg update` to tagname which sets your working directory to the correct revision.  Given delta compression that's not necessarily much larger, and if it is you can automate cloning the bulk of it from a previous local clone.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can also use #. However the problem is, as my question states, not having the tag changeset in the clone, so I don't know at which tag is clone is.

Comment: Huh?  It looks like you know the name and that name is `foo`.  So you can do `hg clone http://host/path#foo`.  If you really don't know the tag's name you should clone everything and then update -- there's no harm in having extra revs in your repo but not your working dir.

Comment: Sorry I meant "at which tag **the** clone is", since the clone doesn't have the `foo` tag changeset. Of course I knew right after the clone, but not after a while (I have terrible short term memory). As you said, doing a full clone then update is an obvious solution, and I always do that anyway. It's just that the `clone parent#foo` semantic feels a bit weird without getting the tag changeset.

Answer (score 1):

There is a postclone hook.  It's called `post-clone` (the hgrc manpage shows a `post-ANYCOMMAND` and `pre-ANYCOMMAND` exist) though as you pointed out you could also use `*changegroup` or `update` hooks too, since clone uses both of those functions (unless you suppress update with `-U`).

What about just adding a `--localtag` so you have the name but not the extra changeset if you need it for reference only.  Something like

```
hg clone -r tagname URL
hg tag --local tagname
```

which you could easily build into a shell alias.

Other than that there's not necessarily guaranteed to be a way to have revision X and the revision where revision X is tagged without also having other revisions you don't want since the tag could have been applied after other work was done.  You can, of course, always update to 'X' and to have subsequent changesets in you working dir, but they'll still be in your repo.

Honestly, once I figured out that the tag name doesn't come a long when you clone up to a tag, which I admit confused the heck out of me at first, I didn't find any need to bring along the changeset with the tag in it.

Comment: Thanks for the `post-clone` hook. I removed "and since there's no `postclone` hook" from the question. I don't quite like the local tag since I'll pull in the tag changeset some time later for sure. Also without the tag changeset, I may commit a tag myself, then I'll have to merge the tags.

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfect but there's no way to do it w/o pulling additional changesets that you might not yet want (all those between the work and the tagging cset).  At least tags merge seamlessly and the local's can't conflict or get pushed.

Comment: I'll only pull the tag changeset if it's the only child of the tagged. @Richard's answer gave me the idea to use a pre-clone and pre-pull hook to check for the case and change the clone/pull revision to the tag changeset. Will post back.