# Problem of hg clone src#tag dest

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository named master which keeps product releases. It has several tags (such as 1.0,2.0,3.0) as baseline. When I want to create hot fix for one version, for example 1.0. I use command as following:

```
hg clone master#1.0 hotfix_1.0.1
cd hotfix_1.0.1
hg tip

changeset:   14:b2492c2611a1
tag:         tip
user:        codingboy <codingboy@gmail.com>
date:        Thu Dec 09 14:03:23 2010 +0800
summary:     fix bug4
```

I find tip version is what I need, but is not tagged with 1.0. It will cause my changes in hotfix_1.0.1 can not be push to master. the error is

```
(abort) unknown 1.0 revision.
```

I check master repository. the log shows below

```
changeset:   15:3497c46cbc7f
tag:         tip
user:        codingboy <codingboy@gmail.com>
date:        Thu Dec 09 14:03:27 2010 +0800
summary:     Added tag 1.0 for changeset b2492c2611a1

changeset:   14:b2492c2611a1
tag:         1.0
user:        codingboy <codingboy@gmail.com>
date:        Thu Dec 09 14:03:23 2010 +0800
summary:     fix bug4
```

so it seems cloned repository lost changset#15. My understanding is hg clone src#tag dest should clone tag which I need. But this operation can not clone child of changeset#14 which is do tagging. So what I have done is to use command

```
hg clone master hotfix_1.0.1 -u 1.0
```

I do not like this command. if master repository is huge and I just want to fix old version, It will waste time to clone and push changes.

Do I have any other approach to clone one repository from one baseline or tag correctly?

thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate with my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770889/how-to-get-the-tag-changeset-after-you-clone-or-pull-to-a-tag-using-mercurial). I said in one of my comments that a pre-clone and pre-pull hook to change the rev argument to include the tag changeset (if it's the only child) would be the best solution, but I never got a chance to actually do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the design of Mercurial tags, the tagged revision does not contain that tag.  In other words, 1.0 doesn't "know" it's 1.0.

Mercurial [recommends](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag#How_do_tags_work_in_Mercurial.3F) the solution you give at the end.  A possible mitigation for the performance issues is to keep (pulling as needed) a single clone of master that you don't modify.  Then, (as needed) clone that locally and update to the desired version.  The clone will (assuming same volume and a modern filesystem) use [hard links](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HardlinkedClones), minimizing the required copying.